# Calling Methods In Java - Hello World Example

Tags: java, methods

I am slowly but surely working my way through java and have gotten a program to work.  However, the program I am using has all of the code in the main method and I'd like to use other methods to keep things better organized.

My question is very simple so I will use the simplest of examples.  Say I wanted to create a Hello World program like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test();
    }

    public void Test(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

How do I call Test() correctly in java?  The way I have written it creates a compiler error.  I am coming from R which would allow something like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you researched the compiler error? Remember, Java is an OO language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your method should be named `test` (not "Test"). Also, it should be (in this case) `static`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
}

public static void test(){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Or, you could also write it like so,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().test(); // Need an instance of HelloWorld to call test on.
}

public void test() { //<-- not a static method.
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elliot.  I will do further research on static.  That aspect of the language is definitely tripping me up.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch -There is no need to change the name of the method,it will work fine this way too. But,to be precise,in Java it is kinda tradition to name the first block-name of method to be smaller character and rest block-name to be capital character.

Answer (score 0):

See,what you have done with your code is that you have called a **non-static method** from a static method which is "**public static void main(String[] args)**" here. Later on,with the time you will come to know that static members are the very first to be called by the compiler and then follows the normal flow of non-static members.

In Java,to call a non-static method,either you need to **create a Class object** to call a non-static method from the main() method,or you itself declare the **non-static method as a static method**,which might not be good in every case,but that would simply be called in the main() method as it is!

Correct code(if you want to call non-static methods from a static-method)  :-

```
 public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld().Test();
 }

 public void Test(){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

Alternative code(if you want to call non-staticmethod from a static-method,make the former  static)  :-

```
public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Test();
 }

 public static void Test(){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method Test() needs to be declared as static, so:

```
public static void Test(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
```

or you can create a new HelloWorld object and then having it call Test():

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     HelloWorld foo = new HelloWorld();
     food.Test();
}
```