# Class not calling in processing IDE

Tags: java, oop, processing

this is a very simple question which is confusing me quite a bit since I have done OOP in Java before and never had this issue. Basically when I go to call the class to create the object in question it's just not happening I have no Idea why this won't work, I assuming it might be misuising a bit of processing simplified java.

```
final color RED = color(255,0,0);
final color BLUE = color(0,0,255);

motorbike bike1;
motorbike bike2;

class motorbike
{
int x = 5;
//members
int y;
int speed=2;
int size=30;
color colour;

void render()
{
  float wheelHeight = size/3;
  fill(colour);
  triangle(x,y,x+size,y,x+size/2,y-size/2);
  //built-in triangle routine
  drawWheel(x,y,wheelHeight);
  drawWheel(x+size,y,wheelHeight);
}

void drawWheel( int x, int y,float size)
{
  float inner = size*2/3;
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x,y,size,size);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y,inner,inner);
}

void move() 
{
  speed= (int)random(5.0);
  //a random step [0..5]
  x=x+speed;
}
void update()  {
  move();
  render();
}

motorbike(int y,color col){
  //constructor
  this.y=y;
  this.speed= (int)random(5.0);
  this.colour=col;
}


//endof class description
}

void setup()
{
  size(500,100);
  bike1 = new motorbike(RED,30);
  bike2 = new motorbike(BLUE,60);
  print("Come on");
}

void draw()
{
  background(125);
}
```

Sorry for the really dumb question but this should be calling I don't know why it's not drawing the object.

Comment: can you share full declaration? I need to test and send you feedback and solution

Comment: The above is the full code It might look off because it's in processing.

Comment: Your `draw()` method does nothing but set the background. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You're never calling any of the functions in your class. In the future, please try to use standard naming conventions (classes and constructors start with upper-case letters, methods and variables start with lower-case letters) and post a [mcve] instead of your whole program.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor has the parameters (int, color).

```
motorbike(int y,color col)
```

You are passing the parameters in the wrong order (color, int)

```
bike1 = new motorbike(RED,30);
```

You also have to [call your functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713643/how-to-call-a-method-in-java) from your recently created object bike1.

```
bike1.render();
```

As you are working with Processing, these methods need to be invoked in `draw()` and perhaps `render()` once in `setup()`

Comment: Yeah I just switched them and it's still not rendering anything.

Comment: Did you call your functions with the object bike1 for example?

Comment: Yes it's literally the same as the above code but the variables are the right way around.

Comment: Check my answer again, or check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901420/calling-methods-in-java-hello-world-example)

Comment: I understand your answer and I have applied it while calling the object it is still not working. There is more wrong here then me just mixing up the color and int parameters.

Comment: In *Processing* (which is related to but distinct from Java) it simply isn't true that you need a main method.

Comment: @AlexBlasco No problem. Processing is a fun language with a gentle learning curve if you already know Java. The comparison isn't exact, but in Processing the function `draw()` is sort of like `main()`. Your remark that OP needs to call the functions is spot-on. You could say a bit more: these methods need to be invoked in `draw()` (and perhaps `render()` once in `setup()`.